# How to pull out data using power query from 1 cell (link pasted in cell A1) from sheet 1 to Sheet 2?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a link of a website from where I want to pull out data through power query. Every time, this link will get changed as per need. So I need to use power query every time. Is there any way to build up power query which shows that I'll change link and data will be refreshed? Is it possible that I paste link in cell A1 of sheet 1 and I fetch data to sheet 2? Please guide me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the cell with the URL, then open menu Power Query > Excel Data > From Table (uncheck "My table has headers")

In the Power Query editor, right click on the URL cell of the table and "drill down" to get the text value.

Now you need to do some manual M code transformation to treat this variable as a datasource. Go to View > Show formula bar, then click the *fx* button to add a custom step. Add the datasource call, e.g. for web pages:

```
= Web.Page(Web.Contents(Column1))
```

You might need to answer some questions about data privacy (after all, you're copying a variable from your Excel workbook and sending it to the internet!).

You can edit the link in sheet 1, and when you refresh your query you'll see sheet 2 is changed.

**EDIT:**

Your full query should look like:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    Column1 = #"Changed Type"{0}[Column1],
    Custom1 = Web.Page(Web.Contents(Column1))
in
    Custom1
```

Comment: Thank you Carl for responding to this question. I have tried but it did not work as I am not getting fx button in query. So i manually tried to type query as follows:let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    Column1 =  Web.Page(Web.Contents(Column1))"{0}[Column1]
in
    Column1  But this gives me an error. Could you please guide me further?

Comment: I'm not able to add snap. Also formatting is not good when I type text.

Comment: Your query seemed to have a syntax error, which can be hard to understand. I updated answer with the full code, you should be able to replace your query with mine from the View > Advanced Editor dialog.

Comment: Thanks Carl for modifying query. It does not give any syntex error but it is not pulling data properly. In my data there are more than one data types and it is not correctly picking it up. Is there any other way?

Comment: I'd start with From Web and see in the Advanced Editor what the current query looks like (e.g. there could be automatic steps to transform the columns). You could edit that information into your original question?

Comment: Actually I am new to power query so I didn't have much idea about writing syntex. So would you please guide me in detail?(if possible)

Comment: Sure, M syntax is a little different than other programming languages. This page has exact destiption of M syntax and behavior: https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Learn-about-Power-Query-formulas-6bc50988-022b-4799-a709-f8aafdee2b2f (look for the PDFs you can download). Here's a guide to using some Power Query features: http://sharepointpromag.com/office-365/using-power-query-office-365-m-language-and-data-transformations Here's