# Dynamic cell via parameter

Tags: powerquery

I am trying to find how to do the following. I need to fill a string (a word) in a column that I can change from a table.  Static way:  Add Column > In formula ="FORD"  So it fills all existing rows in the columns  Variable way:  If I change to HONDA the cell at the table, use  the new word in the query  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/31522846/771768 will work:

> Click on the Excel cell with HONDA, then open menu Power Query > Excel
>   Data > From Table (uncheck "My table has headers")
>
> In the Power Query editor, right click on the HONDA cell of the table
>   and "drill down" to get the text value, and change your add column step to use this `Column1`
>
> You can edit the value in sheet 1, and when you refresh your query
>   you'll see sheet 2 is changed.